# Define an inner product and compute properties.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that the function $$\textit{B}: \mathbb{R}^3\times  
> \mathbb{R}^3$$ given by
>   $$B(u,v)= \begin{pmatrix}
> u^1, &u^2,  &u^3 
> \end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 &1  &1 \\
> 1 &2  &0 \\
> 1 &0  &3
> \end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
> v^1\\v^2 
> \\ v^3 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> defines an inner product;compute the lengths of the vectors $$a=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 &1  &0 
> \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$b=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &1  &1 
> \end{pmatrix}$$ as well as the angle between them with respect to the inner product $\textit{B}$.
>   I have 
>   $$B(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}
>  u^1&u^2  &u^3 
> \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
> {v^1+v^2+v^3}\\ {v^1+2v^2}
> \\{v^1+3v^3}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   and I know
>   $$\text{Length} = \sqrt {1^2+1^2+0^2}$$and$$
> \text{Length} =\sqrt {0^2+1^2+1^2}$$ and $$\text{Angle} = \arccos(a\cdot b)$$
>   But where to from here?

Comment: In computing $B(u,v)$, you stopped before you were finished.  And your computations of the lengths failed to take $B$ into account. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three properties that define an inner product:

1. (Conjugate) Symmetry.  Prove that for any vectors $v, w \in \Bbb R^3$, $B(v,w) = B(w,v)$.
2. Linearity in the first/ second argument.  You automatically get this from the fact that this IP is described by a $3\times 3$ real matrix, but you can test it anyway.  Prove that for any vectors $u, v, w \in \Bbb R^3$ and any real number $t$, $B(u + tv, w) = B(u,w) + tB(v,w)$.
3. Positive-definiteness.  Prove that for any vector $v\in \Bbb R^3$, $B(v,v) \ge 0$ where equality implies $v=0$.

Each of these can be proven component-wise.  That's where you go next.

Then after you've done that you should consider what "lengths ... **with respect  to the inner product $B$**" might mean.  It doesn't just mean "regular old definition of length that you're used to".